# Update table by calculating values from other table of last month

Tags: sql-server, database

In SQL-server database I want to update the table1 with the value of table2, I have two tables pay_tbl and bill_tbl. Those two have the following attributes.

```
pay_tbl
    pay_ID type int -->pk
    outstanding_amount type int

bill_tbl
    pay_ID type int --> Fk
    amount_to_Pay type int
    amount_paid type int
    paid_date type date
    bill_status type varchar
```

I want to update the outstanding_amount column of pay_tbl by adding the value of amount_to_pay column of table2

```
(outstanding_payment+=amount_to_pay)
```

but just update those where bill status is 'Not Paid' and date is last month with respect to current month, i.e: now month is February then only update table where date is in Janurary. I tried following query but I know it is wrong

```
UPDATE pay_tbl 
SET 
    outstanding_payment = outstanding_Payment + 
                          (SELECT 
                               amount_to_pay 
                           FROM bill_tbl INNER JOIN bill_tbl ON
                                bill_tbl.pay_ID = pay_tbl.payID )
WHERE
    MONTH(Date) = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, [Date]))
    AND YEAR(Date) = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, [Date]))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134862/discussion-on-question-by-mjunaid-update-table-by-calculating-values-from-other).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        UPDATE
    TABLE_A
SET
    TABLE_A.OUTSTANDING_PAYMENT = TABLE_A.OUTSTANDING_PAYMENT+TABLE_B.AMOUNT_TO_PAY

FROM
    PAY_TBL AS TABLE_A
    INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT_TO_PAY) AMOUNT_TO_PAY ,PAY_ID FROM BILL_TBL WHERE  MONTH(DATE) =  DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, [DATE]))
AND YEAR(DATE) =    DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, [DATE]))
AND BILL_STATUS='NO PAID'
GROUP BY PAY_ID) AS TABLE_B
        ON TABLE_A.PAY_ID = TABLE_B.PAY_ID
```